# Does a getter have zero cost?

Tags: c++, performance

I have a simple class:

```
class A {
    public:
    int get() const;

    private:
    void do_something();
    int value;
}

int A::get() const {
    return value;
}
```

The getter function is simple and straightforward. Getters are to use them, so in do_something I should use `get()` in order to access `value`. My question is: will compiler optimize-out the getter, so it will be equivalent to accessing the data directly? Or I still will gain performance if I access it directly (what would imply worse design)?

```
A::do_something()
{
    x = get();
    // or...
    x = value;
}
```

Comment: The real question, of course, is: *does it matter* ? Because if it does not, then who cares ? And if it does, then only you can check if your particular compiler does perform the optimization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the method is not virtual, compilers can optimize it. Good compilers (with link-time optimization) can optimize even if the method is not `inline` and defined in separate .cpp file. Not so good ones can only do that if it's declared inside the class definition, or in the header file with `inline` keyword. For virtual methods, it depends, but most likely no.

Comment: nice for mentioning `virtual` thing.

Comment: For virtual functions, it depends on whether the compiler knows the dynamic type or not.  While the most frequent use of virtual functions results in contexts where it cannot, there are exceptions, and I know of at least one idiom which depends on the compiler inlining virtual functions.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler will almost certainly inline such a trivial getter, if it's got access to the definition.

Comment: Will it inline getter without `inline` keyword by defining it outside the class?

Comment: @ks1322: In-class definition of member functions are implicitly declared as `inline`.

Comment: @Nawaz, I am asking will it be inlined in this particular case (no `inline` keyword, member function is defined **outside** of the class)?

Comment: @ks1322, it depends on the quality of the compiler. Visual Studio will inline the function in the default Release configuration.

Comment: @ks1322: Many modern compilers now have linkers that can inline, including Visual Studio and GCC.

Answer (score 2):

If the getter is defined as an inline function (either implicitly by defining it inside the class, or explicitly with the `inline` keyword), the compiler will usually inline it, and there will be no overhead in calling it.

It is, however, common for debug builds to disable inlining, which is perfectly valid since compilers are not required to inline anything.

Answer (score 1):

Well, using get is usually a better design because it hides the actual logic involved in getting the value (today it's a field, tomorrow it may require more complex logic). As for performance, while accessing the value itself will always be at least as fast as using get, the compiler will most likely inline the call anyway.

Answer (score 1):

First you would not be able to manipulate the value *inside* your object if you do not return a reference rather than the value:

```
int& get();
```

Now it returns a reference and can be altered. But imho this is not quite clean, you should also define a setter and use it to write back the altered value:

```
int get() const;
void set(int);

...
A::do_something()
{
    x = get();
    set(value);
}
```

The performance of the setter depends on your compiler. Most modern compilers are able to inline simple getters/setters, so there should not be any performance loss.